# Google Sheet - dynamically fillout table (e.g., calendar) based on ever-growing rows of data - blooming plant list

Tags: google-sheets

I have an online form where user can cite a list of plants blooming in their area, which appends this data to a Google spreadsheet.
The collected data is 1) the date, and 2) a comma separated list of plant names.
I would like to convert this data into a dynamic calendar, which will continue to evolve as new plants are added at different dates.

*edit: [This is a link to a copy of the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/153UAX1LWAJPwZLE-hifStBdCEZiH7LNIDrjq3ukII9A/edit?usp=sharing).*

The resulting spreadsheet will look like:

| Submitted On | What is blooming in your area right now |
| --- | --- |
| 08/19/2023 21:37:44 | crape myrtle, orange cosmos, white clover |
| 08/27/2023 21:37:44 | crape myrtle, orange cosmos, white clover |
| 09/04/2023 21:37:44 | crape myrtle, white clover |
| 08/20/2023 8:06:16 | crape myrtle, sunflower,garden zinnia,melampodium,Rose of Sharon, hibiscus |

In a second sheet, I use a QUERY/ARRAYFORMULA to transmogrify the data to a two column range showing the blooming plant (A) and the ISOWEEKNUM of the date submitted (B).
The formula is:
`=unique(query(ArrayFormula(split(trim(flatten(split(filter( flatten(Sheet1!B2:B), len(flatten(Sheet1!B2:B)) ),",")&"•"&isoweeknum(Sheet1!A2:A))),"•")), "select * where Col2 is not null order by Col1"))`

The result looks like:
|Plants Bloomin|Week of Year|
|---|---|
|crape myrtle   |33|
|crape myrtle   |34|
|crape myrtle   |36|
|garden zinnia  |33|
|hibiscus   |33|
|melampodium    |33|
|orange cosmos  |33|
|orange cosmos  |34|
|Rose of Sharon |33|
|sunflower  |33|
|white clover   |33|
|white clover   |34|
|white clover   |36|

What I would ultimately like to do is to populate a dynamic calendar (or table) with the plant names on the left and the appropriate calendar item toggled on (as I am using the checkbox for visual readability). The calendar/table needs to be dynamic as the list of plants will continue to grow as new species are added.
[image: Converting from a range of data to a calendar/table showing matching weeks]

As it is, my existing calendar/table uses a formula in each box which looks at the column heading for a week number and the row heading for the plant name, and then looks for a corresponding match.
For example, the formula in "H2" is `=ISTEXT(filter($A:$B,$A:$A = $G2,$B:$B = H$1))`
Depending on the result, the box is either true or false.
However, using this per-box formula does not allow for dynamic data growth as new plants are added, requiring me to constantly add additional rows when they become needed. A current workaround would be to generate a few hundred pre-formatted rows with the formula pre-populated.

What I would like is a smart QUERY and/or ARRAYFORMULA that will toggle the weekly boxes, thus constructing the calendar for all the plants. The only way I can imagine this at the moment is to come up with a QUERY which would return 54 columns (one for the plant name and fifty-three for the weekly blocks) ... and no, I have not come up with that query yet.

Any thoughts on how this might be reasonably achieved (without resorting to scripting)? Thank you in advance, my fellow spreadsheet intelligentcia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(row,unique(tocol(map(B2:B,lambda(Σ,index(trim(split(Σ,","))))),3)),
     col,sequence(1,53),
     vstack(hstack(,col),hstack(row,makearray(counta(row),53,lambda(r,c,if(ifna(xmatch(index(col,,c),filter(weeknum(A:A),search(index(row,r),B:B)))),image("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/aa/54/6d/aa546d72e7a56b14408b365f678f1521.png"),))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Well, this answer sho' is freakin' rockin'! Thanks, @rockinfreakshow. A fast response with a very usable answer. Something tells me you have previously had a similar need. Waiting to see if any other answers come in (since knowledge is power), but this will probably be the suggested answer.